# python case insentive string search

Tags: python-3.x, string

I am searching for a list of string from a string "all_data["text"]]"

```
filterwords = ["Hello"]
if any([i for i in filterwords if i in all_data["text"]]):
     print("Has Hello word")
else:
     print("Not found")
```

I want to make this search as case insensitive search. for both filterwords  as well as all_data["text"]]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to convert both sides to a lower case.

**Ex:**

```
filterwords = ["hello"]
if any([i for i in filterwords if i in all_data["text"].lower()]):
     print("Has Hello word")
else:
     print("Not found")
```

OR using Regex wth `re.IGNORECASE`

```
import re
filterwords = ["hello", "world"]

ptrn = re.compile(r"\b(" + "|".join(filterwords) + r")\b", flags=re.IGNORECASE)
print(ptrn)
if any([i for i in filterwords if ptrn.search("Hello")]):
     print("Has Hello word")
else:
     print("Not found")
```